# Create data frame from a list

Tags: r

I am trying to run the below code line to create a data frame from a list with varying sublists of different lengths as you can see in the error. Attached image shows the lists stored under (Table_match_list).

How do we bypass this, so that I would still be able to create a data frame. Any idea please.

CODELINE:
content_table_df    <- as.data.frame(Table_match_list)

ERROR:
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 102, 98, 99

IMAGE:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a in `data.frame`? The premise of the frame is that each row is an "observation", all values on that row are associated together somehow. In your case, RonakShah's answer (that will work) converts three vectors of unrelated observations into associated observations. There is a not-small flaw in this logic. If you know that they were at one point associated like this, then I suggest you go back into whatever processing you did on it that would have reduced the lengths. If not, then projecting that presumption seems wrong.

Comment: HI, That's how the data is. Nothing is reducing the length.

Comment: Actually I need to write something in data extraction so that if the key word is not available in a page then it should print NA so that my lengths will be equal in all sublists.                                                                                                  Table_search        <- list("Table 14","Listing [0-9]","Program")
Table_match_list    <- sapply(Table_search, grep, x = tablelist, value = TRUE)     This code loops through PDF file and searches for the key words. The difference in the length is due to unavailability of key word in a specific file.

Comment: Table_search        <- list("Table 14","Listing [0-9]","Program")
Table_match_list    <- sapply(Table_search, grep, x = tablelist, value = TRUE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get maximum length of `Table_match_list` and append `NA`s for the lists which are shorter.

```
n <- max(lengths(Table_match_list))
content_table_df <- type.convert(as.data.frame(sapply(Table_match_list, `[`, 1:n)), as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Any thoughts Ronak how to print a "NA" in case of non availability of data in a page.         
                        Table_search <- list("Table 14","Listing [0-9]","Program") Table_match_list <- sapply(Table_search, grep, x = tablelist, value = TRUE)

Comment: That should probably be another question but you can try : `Table_match_list <- sapply(Table_search, function(x) {tmp <- grep(x, tablelist, value = TRUE);if(length(tmp)) tmp else NA})`

Comment: I would love to put through as another question, but the system doesnt let me do so until 90 mins.

Comment: This is not working, let me put that through a new thread after a while.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013057/print-na-in-the-cell-if-data-not-available                                                                                                                                               here it is my friend.