# Print NA in the cell if data not available

Tags: r

I am extracting data from multiple PDF's using set of search words.

```r
Table_search <- list("Table 14", "Listing [0-9]", "Program") 

Table_match_list <- sapply(Table_search, grep, x = tablelist, value = TRUE)
```

This code loops through PDF file and searches for the key words and extracts that line from the PDF. I get a difference in length between keywords like the error below. This is due to missing keywords in specific pages, if the code comes across any missing values it should be able to print `NA` so that code goes to next page and looks for keywords and so on.

If I print `NA` for blank cells then my final out put should have equal number of rows for each keyword I search for.

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 102, 98, 99

I asked to search for three words and the output is 102, 98, 99 respectively. Instead I should have 102 rows for each keyword i search for.

Here 102 because I am looping through 102 PDF files.

Please advise how can we achieve this.

Thank you
Bharath

@Ronak ------- Updated This is what I get out of 102 PDF files. 3 Sublists are 3 different keywords. First word is in all PDFs, second word is in 98 PDFs, third one is in 99 PDF's.

[image]

This is what I get from your code.

[image]

How I need is, It doesn't have to print NULL for every line of PDF. Just one NULL per PDF "If keyword is missing".

[image]

TABLELIST IMAGE
[image]

Comment: The error I show didnt trigger from the code line i posted here. That comes when I create a data frame using the match list.

Comment: You can use `tryCatch` in the function you use for finding the line of the keyword.

Comment: Can you include output of `dput(tablelist)` to your post so that I can use the data to verify the answer?

Comment: Are you sure my suggestion in the previous answer doesn't work. Here's a slightly modified version. `Table_match_list <- sapply(Table_search, function(x) {tmp <- grep(x, tablelist, value = TRUE);if(length(tmp) > 0) toString(tmp) else NA})` What does this return?

Comment: Your previous suggestion actually works, the second image is from the your code, where it prints NULL for every line even though all three keywords are available int he PDF. If you see the third image (Desired output) we just want the NULL printed once, if the keyword is not available in the entire page instead of every line. I think a slight modification of your previous answer should work, which I am unable to figure out.

Comment: i have also included(tablelist) output image n the original post

Comment: in the second image i have highlited three areas, they are a match in that PDF which means i have all keaywords in that particular PDF, so we have all information then it doesnt have to print NULL. if suppose any keyword is not available in the PDF then for that particular keyword it should print NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the following :

```
Table_search <- c("Table 14", "Listing [0-9]", "Program") 
Table_match_list <- sapply(Table_search, function(x) {
                      y <- grepl(x, tablelist)
                      y[!y] <- NA
                      tablelist[y]
                     })
```

Comment: This is printing me 2608 rows for each key word with a final list of 7824. This is printing a NULL for every row of a PDF page, this will end up in lot of post processing. Instead this should only print NULL in a consolidated manner for a page, for each keyword

Comment: @Bharath Can't really help without an example data then. I don't know any details about `tablelist`. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Not sure how to upload a PDF, But let me brief you. Imagine a PDF file with 50 lines. From the 50 lines I extract 3 lines using three keywords. For instance if all three key words are available in PDF 1, then the code goes to next PDF. imagine there are only two keywords available so it will extract 2 lines and the third one should be null. So i need only one row per PDF which i get now but if there are any missing keywords in a PDF it should just print NULL for the page alone. Instead the above code is printing NULL for every line of the PDF which means 49 NULLs for each page each keyword.

Comment: If its confusing not to worry please ignore.

Comment: @Bharath Can you edit your post to show how your final output would look like?

Comment: yeah I have updated the post, hope I am clear enough. Let me know if this helps.